# How to force Crashlytics to report more information about the object the crash is related to?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crash-reports, crashlytics

I use Crashlytics to track issues and crashed within my app which is in App stORE currently. The latest report looks like this:

[image]

> Fatal Exception: NSObjectInaccessibleException
>   CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd000000000200002 < x-coredata://DBBBD05E-4333-452C-9EB4-FEBF139B0431/WLWishlist/p8>'

I know that sth is wrong with a subclass of `NSManagedObject`: `WLWishlist`. But I do not have any more information about that object.

**Is it possible to print and report every property of that object along with next issue related to it?**

Comment: What do you expect to print about that object?  It doesn't exist, which is why you are getting the error that the fault can't be fulfilled.

Comment: @JodyHagins I think that it exists, but objects WITH RELATIONS to it doesnt exista. Do I understand it well?

Comment: I don't think so.  What is more likely is that there is some object that has a relationship to the WLWishlist object with objectID x-coredata://DBBBD05E-4333-452C-9EB4-FEBF139B0431/WLWishlist/p8, and that object does not know that the WLWishlist object has been deleted.  Sounds like you may no have setup your relationship deleteRule properly.  Or, it's possible that the object has been deleted, and there is an object reference to it that's alive somewhere, and it tries to access the object causing the crash.  Need more info to help further.

Comment: @JodyHagins Ok I will check it and let you know

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk did you get a fix?